# How to use BufferedReader.readLine().split(" ") java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have this code:

```
public static void opticFiberApplication() throws IOException {
    int v1;
    File file = new File("src/Arcos.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int capacity = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    Graph application = new Graph(capacity);

    while ((v1 = Character.getNumericValue(br.read())) != -1) {
        int v2 = Character.getNumericValue(br.read());
        int cost = Character.getNumericValue(br.read());
        if (application.getVertex(v1) == null) application.addVertex(v1);
        if (application.getVertex(v2) == null) application.addVertex(v2);

        application.addEdge(v1, v2, cost);
    }
    printGraph(application);
    prim(application);
}
```

And the .txt Arcos

```
5
0110025032143238
```

Where the first line is the capacity and the second one are the vertex and the cost of the edge.

---

I want to know how to use BufferedReader.readLine().split(" ") so that Arcos.txt can be read like this

```
5
0 1 10 0 2 5 0 3 2 1 4 3 2 3 8
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How is your program supposed to tell whether the result should be `0 1 10 0`... or `0 1 1 0 0`? Seems like you should be formatting your text file differently.

Comment: It's a sequence, the first two numbers are the v1 and v2 and the third number is the cost of the edge linking the vertexes

Comment: @SantiagoAmbrosetti The problem is that there's no way to distinguish the numbers in a string like `01100...` if there's also numbers with more than a single digit.

Comment: @SantiagoAmbrosetti you are missing the point. look at this sequence: 5320342. It could mean v1=5, v2=3, cost=20. Or it could mean v1=5, v2=3, cost=2. There is no way to tell.

Comment: @SantiagoAmbrosetti please consider closing the question and marking the answer as completed if it satisfies you

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confused as to what `Split` is.

`public String[] split(String regex)` - Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. What you are looking for is this:

```
for (int i = 0;i < str.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```